# Htaccess Rewrite root to a folder without showing to end user

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Rewrite http://domain.com to http://domain.com/site (the actual files are in folder 'site')

And let the user see no change in url (he types http://domain.com) and the content is delivered from site folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It redirects to http://domain.com/site but shows the same url. I need to show http://domain.com

Comment: @Abhishek something else is redirecting you then, there's nothing in the above rules that will redirect the browser.

Comment: I would need the url to remain the same to the end user (http://domain.com) while internally rewrite to (http://domain.com/site)

Comment: @Abhishek I understand what you are asking, and I've given you the rules to do exactly that. The tester you are using is telling you the wrong thing. [As you can see, with those rules, in a blank document root except a "site" folder with a "test.html" file, I can access `/test.html` and it DOESN'T redirect me, instead serving the file that exists in `/site/`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cAWoe.png)

Comment: I see the issue here. I have an index.php inside site folder. When I user http://domain.com/index.php it fetches the one from the folder without changing the url. But if I simply use http://domain.com/ it fetches the same index.php file but the url changes to http://domain.com/site/

Comment: @Abhishek Try adding this rule right below the `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteRule ^$ /site/index.php [L]`

Comment: That's not working but I mark your answer as it works for all the files. Will find out more about this issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect every request url in the folder `/` to `site/` for example `a.php` to `site/a.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ site/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or try google: http://www.htaccessredirect.net/